# Google Compute Engine Quotas silently changing?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've been using GCE for several weeks with free credits and have repeatedly found that the quota values keep changing.  The default CPU quota is 24 per region, but, depending on what other APIs I enable and in what order, that can silently change to 2 or 8.  And today when I went to use it the CPU quota had again changed from 24 to 2 even though I hadn't changed what APIs were enabled.  Disabling then re-enabling Compute Engine put the quota back to 24, but that is not a very satisfactory solution.  This seems to be a bug to me.  Anyone else have this problem and perhaps a solution?  I know about the quota increase request form, but it says that if I request an increase than that is the end of my free credits.

Answer (score 0):

[Free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/index#FAQ) in GCE has some limitation as only 2 concurrent cores at a time, so if for some reason you were able to change it to 24 cores, it's expected that it will be back at 2 cores.